# Getting 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found on building dart-sqlite

Tags: sqlite, dart

Here is dart-sqlite: https://github.com/sam-mccall/dart-sqlite

trying to build it because I need 32bit version. Also is it possible to get it in 32bit?

I set path to dart-sdk, set path to sqlite sources and trying to build:

```
D:\Contrib\dart-sqlite>build
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

dart_sqlite.cc
src\dart_sqlite.cc(42) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(43) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(44) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(97) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(121) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(123) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(124) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(195) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(229) : error C3861: 'Dart_NewString': identifier not found
src\dart_sqlite.cc(266) : error C3861: 'Dart_IsString8': identifier not found
Generating Code...
Compiling...
sqlite3.c
Generating Code...
```

Must I switch compiler..? or is there something I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick look at the latest sdk header file Dart_NewString does not exist anymore. The following signatures are available, so you might need to update sam's code.

```
16:53:48-adam@Adams-MacBook-Air:~/dart_bleeding/dart/runtime/include
$ grep -r Dart_NewString *
dart_api.h:DART_EXPORT Dart_Handle Dart_NewStringFromCString(const char* str);
dart_api.h:DART_EXPORT Dart_Handle Dart_NewStringFromUTF8(const uint8_t* utf8_array,
dart_api.h:DART_EXPORT Dart_Handle Dart_NewStringFromUTF16(const uint16_t* utf16_array,
dart_api.h:DART_EXPORT Dart_Handle Dart_NewStringFromUTF32(const uint32_t* utf32_array,
```

Comment: Looking at the code in sqlight its a bit dated. I'll do a little digging and might be able to patch it up to the latest dart sdk.

Comment: Please let me know if you can update it or if there is any update of it

Answer (score 2):

Most uses of Dart_NewString in our code have been replaced by a utility function NewString:

```
// Create a new Dart String object from a C String.
static Dart_Handle NewString(const char* str) {
  ASSERT(str != NULL);
  return Dart_NewStringFromUTF8(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(str),
                                strlen(str));
}
```

You could include this utility function in dart_sqlite, or just use Dart_NewStringFromUTF8 directly.

There may be additional problems, because the Dart executable now includes the sqlite library, as part of NSS (Network Security Services, from Mozilla), which is used to implement secure sockets in dart:io.

Comment: eeh... so I can use it just out from the box... may you provide embedded sqlite example or point to docs please?